# How to get text after the match REGEX if its below the match

Tags: regex, uipath

I'm new to regex but I wanted to know if there was a way to find the text below a lookahead

```
(?<=Name:)(.*(\s))
```

the type of text

```
Name: Richard V.
```

or

```
Name: 

Richard V.
```

Comment: Use the `s` flag to make `.` match newlines.

Comment: Is there a reason for use of the lookahead, why not just capture? [`Name:\s*(.+)`](https://regex101.com/r/aCWbXH/1)